# React setState default value type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to React, but I struggle to find the error in what I am writing.

The objective is to show a list of users, asking it to a server via `socket.io`. My original code is as follows:

```
// the list of users
const [users, setUsers] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    if (socket == null) return

    // listen once to the get user event
    socket.once('load-users', userList => {
        console.log('received type', typeof(userList), ':', userList)
        setUsers(userList)
    })

    console.log('emitting get users')
    // ask the server for the users
    socket.emit('get-users', {all: true})
}, [socket, users])
```

When rendering the component I wanted to return a simple list:

```
return (
    <ul>
        {users.map((user) => <li key={user.name}>{user.name} | {user.password}</li>)}
    </ul>
)
```

This gives me an ominous error in the browser:

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
undefined is not a function (near '...users.map...')
Dashboard@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:184:24
...
```

After some hours struggling I tried to **initialize the state to an array**

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
```

And lo and behold, it works! The real problem is that I don't know why.

Why is the **initial** type of the state so important? Why `setState` can't change it?

Comment: renders before users is set

Comment: so basically it doesnt wait till you set the users (asynchronous). when it tries to render it finds that users is undefined because u didn't initialize. in that case you can have a loader until the data arrives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` runs **after** the component renders in an async way. So in your first render, the `users` variable is `undefined` and therefore calling the `map` method fails. That code would be the same as doing something like this:

```js
let users;

window.setTimeout(() => {
  users = [];
}, 0);

return users.map(() => {});
```

Since the setTimeout (useEffect) will execute after the `map` function call this will error out with the exact same error.